# Is there any way to measure a 3D objects height, width and length using point-cloud data?

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, point-clouds, measurement

I am working on a pet project. I want to develop a system where I can measure a 3D object's height, width, and length. But, the fact is that I wish the measurement to be done automatically from the 3D point cloud without any intervention from me or needing the help of any reference object.
To be more precise, the object is in a point-cloud format encapsulated in a 3D bounding box.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can analyze geomdl, rhino3dm and verb.py libraries. You can use bounding box to get object and analyze height, width and surface area of the 3D object.